# H12 Request timeout 503 on heroku then 200 success

Tags: ruby, heroku, sinatra

I am running a small docker image that starts a ruby Sinatra API. Th point of the API is to receive an image, preprocess it using a script then use Tesseract OCR to return the text from the image.

The issue I'm having is that I'm getting a 503 error then a 300 success with the text, but it's of no use as my ios app has already received the 503 error and continued on its way.

```
require 'sinatra'
require "json"
require 'sinatra/base'
require 'sinatra'
require 'json'
require 'fileutils'
require 'tempfile'
require "base64"
require 'puma_worker_killer'

PumaWorkerKiller.enable_rolling_restart

set :protection, except: [ :json_csrf ]
port = ENV['PORT'] || 8080
set :port, port
set :bind, '0.0.0.0'

post '/extractText' do
  begin
    bas64Image = Base64.decode64(params[:image])
    imageFile = Tempfile.new(['image', '.png'])
    imageFile.write(bas64Image)
    imageFile.close
    `textcleaner #{imageFile.path} #{imageFile.path}`
    # `textdeskew #{imageFile.path} #{imageFile.path}`
    output = `tesseract #{imageFile.path} --psm 6 --oem 2 stdout`
    p output
  rescue
    status 402
    return "Error reading image"
  end
  status 200
  return output
end
```

Heres the heroku read out i get:

```
2017-10-23T20:22:00.548029+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=POST path="/extractText" host=tesseractimageserver.herokuapp.com request_id=7b179829-ef1f-4e18-844b-42b90a5c5c69 fwd="82.32.79.208" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30945ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2017-10-23T20:22:42.864098+00:00 app[web.1]: "Returned text from reading image using tesseract"
2017-10-23T20:22:42.872633+00:00 app[web.1]: 82.32.79.208 - - [23/Oct/2017:20:22:42 +0000] "POST /extractText HTTP/1.1" 200 467 72.2921
```

Id there a way around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how it works. Heroku has 30 seconds timeout for any web request. When the new request is routed to your application dyno and there is no response within this 30 seconds time limit, Heroku is dropping the connection and reporting H12 error. But your dyno is still processing the web request, even nobody will ever use its response. The client is already gone. Because of such behavior it is recommended to put some kind of timeout mechanism on long-running actions. If you send many requests to such endpoint you can easily bring your whole application to a halt.

The work-around to this problem is to process your images in background job. So the first request will register a new job and return its id or some kind of identifier. Then your ios app can periodically ping server using this id to check if the job has finished.

Comment: Mlozniak What timeout mechanism on long-running actions should we use for those cases?